# Foursquare Venue API returning empty venue list

Tags: java, foursquare

I am working on the FourSquare venue API.
The following API link was giving results until this morning at 3 AM:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-6.21944223,106.80315059&intent=browse&radius=30&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&v=20180512&m=foursquare

but now there is an empty venue array with status code 200. There is no update on the developer website.

Please help me understand why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a change to a web site.

Comment: The same happened to me. Try selecting some categoryId parameters. I believe somehow the categoryId is not optional anymore.

Comment: @FelipeFerri Is categoryId working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my app. Up until a couple of weeks ago we were able to make requests to the Foursquare api without specifying category ids. By doing this all place categories were considered. But now if you ommit categoryId no place is returned at all. I don't know if this is a bug on the Foursquare api or just a feature change (a VERY BREAKING change).

While we don't know the real answer, try adding a "categoryId" to your request, such as:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?
    client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}
    &client_secret={YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET}
    &v=20130815&ll={LATITUDE},{LONGITUDE}
    &limit=50
    &intent=browse
    &radius=50
    &categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259
```

(the indentation on the URL above is just for legibility, you should pass this URL as a single line when doing your request)

Answer (score 1):

As @FelipeFerri suggested, I have added following parameter in API and it start giving the result.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-6.21944223,106.80315059&intent=browse&radius=30&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&v=20180512&m=foursquare&&categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259

Thanks

Comment: @Andrew I don't understand your comment. Can you please help to understand.

Comment: It's more of a self answer than a thanks, but Felipe should of written his comment as an answer, and that should be accepted.

Comment: @Andrew  Agree with you. Thanks

Comment: I've written a proper answer. I'm glad it worked for you Nitendra.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me. I've changed the API version (v) also without any

Comment: Can you please provide the detail of which version you change the API.Please provide a api which giving the result. It will be very helpfull